# The ordinal 4445 could not be located in dynamic link library: libeay32.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-7-x64

Recently I upgraded my project from 32 bit to 64 bit using Visual Studio 2008. Installed my application on Windows 7 64 bit version. When I tried to run my application it throws the following error

```
The ordinal 4445 could not be located in dynamic link library: libeay32.dll
```

Can anyone time tell me what causes this error and how to fix it.

I tried dependency walker, and found mfc42u.dll was in x86. So I replaced it with x64 version. But still I see the problem.

Any help would be great!!!

`update 1:` I tried the steps from this link but no use
http://www.joyfax.com/faqs/joyfax_mail_ssl.html

Comment: I don't suppose you provided a 64-bit version of libeay (and linked against it, and distributed it with your application installation) when doing your port?

Comment: My first doubt was that, so I downloaded 64 bit version and replaced it manually after installation.

Comment: The first thing to check is that you're supposed to be using `libeay32` in a 64-bit project. Depending on whether it's just a legacy name, that may be an issue. After that, you need to make sure your `.lib` file and the library version match up; this error means that a function listed by ordinal (index in the export table) can't be found, which is fairly common of mismatching versions.